# If my company is using Okta to authenticate to Artifactory, what do I put for an encrypted password in settings.xml?

Tags: artifactory, okta

Unlike using a regular username and login for JFrog Artifactory, my company uses Okta that then lets us login to everything else (JIRA, AWS, Gmail, etc) with one username & password.

When I login to Artifactory, I created a Maven settings.xml from [these instructions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository).  That produced something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>rshillington@mycompany.com</username>
      <password>*** Insert encrypted password here ***</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>rshillington@mycompany.com</username>
      <password>*** Insert encrypted password here ***</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
...
```

What do I replace `*** Insert encrypted password here ***` with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After logging in to Artifactory, click on your name in the upper right hand corner.  Then you'll have the opportunity to create an API key.  Create one of those and copy that into the password elements of `settings.xml` everywhere that you see `*** Insert encrypted password here ***`.